# Are STL predicates allowed to use their argument's address?

Tags: c++, stl, predicate, remove-if

When writing a custom predicate function/functor to pass to an STL algorithm, is the predicate allowed to use the address of its argument?

Here's the problem that inspired the question. I have a vector `vec`, and a vector `inds`, which contains some indices into `vec`. I'd like to remove those elements in `vec` whose indices are listed in `inds`.

One approach is to use `remove_if` with a predicate functor `InInds` that determines its argument's index in `vec` by taking its address:

```
class InInds {
  private:

  const vector<Element>& vec_;
  const vector<int>& inds_;

  public:

  InInds(const vector<Element>& vec, const vector<int>& inds) 
    : vec_(vec), inds_(inds) {}

  bool operator()(const Element& element) {
    // WARNING: uses the ADDRESS of element, not its value. May not be kosher?
    int index = &element - &vec[0];
    return std::find(inds_.begin(), inds_.end(), index) != inds_.end();
  }

}
```

`InInds` works if called directly on an element in `vec`. It will break if it's called on a copy of an element, since the copy's address will not be useful to determine `element`'s index.

My question is: will this predicate work in `remove_if` for any standards-compliant compiler? Or are predicates strictly meant to operate only on values, not addresses?

Comment: Just use a loop. Trying to make algorithms fit where they don't fit isn't going to help anything.

Comment: @NicolBolas Should I infer from your answer that using addresses in predicates is definitely not standards-compliant?

Comment: Whether it is or not is irrelevant; it's easier and much clearer to all involved to just write a loop.

Comment: I would say that whether it's clearer is irrelevant to the question as asked ;) It was, as you'll note, a question about standards, not style.

Answer (score 1):

Use of remove_if with your predicate is wrong since remove_if usually moves undeleted elements toward the beginning of the range. You need to copy undeleted elements to another container instead of removing them in place.